# Android App says "Can't Play this video" when provided with link

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I developed a small android app to which a link is provided and it just need to play that video.
But playback says "Can't play this video".
Can anyone help me with this.?

Main Activity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final VideoView ramVV= (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.ramVV);

    ramVV.setVideoPath("https://www.thenewboston.com/forum/project_files/006_testVideo.mp4");
    ramVV.start();
}
```

}

logcat shows the following:

```
  07-18 22:24:19.925  17364-17364/com.example.ram.videoplayer D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3eb3e80, tid 17364
  07-18 22:24:20.015  17364-17364/com.example.ram.videoplayer D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
  07-18 22:24:20.059  17364-17379/com.example.ram.videoplayer D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3eb3fd0, tid 17379
  07-18 22:24:20.076  17364-17379/com.example.ram.videoplayer I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
  07-18 22:24:20.110  17364-17379/com.example.ram.videoplayer D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
  07-18 22:24:20.117  17364-17379/com.example.ram.videoplayer W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
  07-18 22:24:20.117  17364-17379/com.example.ram.videoplayer W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3f1ec20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
  07-18 22:24:20.167  17364-17364/com.example.ram.videoplayer D/MediaPlayer﹕ Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
  07-18 22:24:50.612  17364-17378/com.example.ram.videoplayer E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
  07-18 22:24:50.612  17364-17364/com.example.ram.videoplayer E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
  07-18 22:24:50.612  17364-17364/com.example.ram.videoplayer D/VideoView﹕ Error: 1,-2147483648
  07-18 22:24:50.703  17364-17379/com.example.ram.videoplayer W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
  07-18 22:24:50.703  17364-17379/com.example.ram.videoplayer W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3feb960, error=EGL_SUCCESS
  07-18 22:24:53.600  17364-17379/com.example.ram.videoplayer D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa512fd80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa51358f0
```

And I have also added permission in Manifest file.

Comment: I just tried the exact same code on my device and it worked. Moto X 2014 running Android 5.1. What device and OS are you testing on?

Comment: I'm testing on Android emulator (by taking Galaxy Nexus android 5.1.1)

Comment: Its a known fact that video playing has issues on an Emulator. I'd suggest you to try it on an emulator.